# How to execute command from Iron python script (not cmd.exe)?

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7, exe, ironpython

I was looking at this question :

[Execute terminal command from python in new terminal window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308415/execute-terminal-command-from-python-in-new-terminal-window)

and was wondering how can I send a command with 2 arguments to a shell that is not cmd.exe
I have my own shell , that is familiar with my command , but I want it to run from a python script.

something like :

```
def func(path_to_exe, command_name, arg1, arg2):
 execute(path_to_exe, "command_name arg1 arg2")
```

I saw that using sub process can help, but all the examples are using command line

thanks!

Comment: I would recommend this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python?rq=1)

Comment: thanks, I looked there but as I see - all are running from command line, and I need it to run from my exe

Comment: I don't understand, how is your shell running?

Comment: What's wrong with this - `from subprocess import call;
call([path_to_exe, "command_name arg1 arg2"]);` (Using the command line)