# Using Popen to open a Program as its own independant file

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using `subprocess.Popen` to control programs in a tasks scheduler.

The code I am using to open programs is:

```
subprocess.Popen("python " + filename + ".py")
```

The problem I am facing is this (I am using Python):

When I run my taskscheduler from the Python IDLE, everything runs as expected.  However, when I run the task scheduler from the command line, The programs that open actually run in the same "shell" or command window as the task scheduler itself.

I don't want this to happen.  I have played with the `shell=True` command, but I haven't gotten it to work yet.  Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308415/execute-terminal-command-from-python-in-new-terminal-window

Comment: What do you mean they run in the same "shell"?  Can you describe a little better what you're seeing (and what you want to be seeing?)

Comment: are you trying to say that you want to run the program on a separate shell?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the notes.  So, I run the taskscheduler using windows task scheduler.  So I am running my own scheduler using windows task scheduler.  When I run it, all the programs that open using Popen, run within the task scheduler window (all the print statements I have to confirm that the program is running and not errored).  I want the programs to each run in their own "shells".  The reason I quote shells, is because I am not sure if that is the right vocab.