# How do I launch a separate python script with a python script while keeping both?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I have tried subsystem and os and both will not work. I would prefer it if they were in 2 separate windows.

My current code is

```
os.system('cmd.exe /c Bot.py ' + user)
```

I have also tried

```
subprocess.Popen(['python', 'Bot.py', user])
```

and

```
subprocess.Popen(['python', 'Bot.py', user, '&'])
```

Bot.py is a irc bot. The bot will connect to the irc but not receive any messages after the connection. The bot works fine if executed alone.

Comment: Are you actually assigning the result of the ``Popen`` call to a variable? If not it can be arbitrarily deleted (and thus the process killed) at any time. Also, the semantics of ``Popen`` are slightly different on Windows and Linux, so stating your OS might help (I'd guess Windows based on your first line, but better to be explicit)

Comment: I have tried assigning it to a variable and I have windows.

Comment: It's not clear to me why, since you want them in separate windows, you don't simply start them separately form the command line?

Comment: Have you tried: **os.system("start /wait cmd /c Bot.py")**  ?

Comment: @aruisdante: the process *won't* be killed only because OPs code doesn't keep a reference to Popen() object. `subprocess` has `_active` list that holds Popen objects that are still running while their `__del__` method are called.

Comment: related: [Execute terminal command from python in new terminal window?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19308415/4279)

Comment: @ Midnighter Its so someone can put my irc bot in there channel without needing me to do it manually.