# Python GUI running multi command lines at the same time in different shells

Tags: python, multithreading, shell, user-interface, subprocess

I want to run multi command lines by clicking different buttons using python GUI ?

for example I have button1 and button2 when I click button1 a command line will be excuted and when I press button2 another shell should be opened and new command line will be runned withour stopping the firat one.

I read about it but I didn't find the suitable code for that

What I wrote is the following:

```
   class Application(Frame):
    """A GUI """
    def __init__(self,master):
    Frame.__init__(self,master)
    self.grid()
    self.create_widgets() 

def create_widgets(self):
    #create first button 
    self.button = Button(self, text="roscore", command=self.roscore)    
    self.button.grid()

    #create first button 1
    self.button1 = Button(self, text="rqt plot", command=self.open_rqt) 
    self.button1.grid()




def open_rqt(self):
    call(["rosrun", "rqt_plot", "rqt_plot"])

def roscore(self):
    call(["roscore"])




root = Tk()  
root.title("GUI") 
root.geometry("1000x1000") 
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: I saw this link but i didnt know how to use it in my code... It is my first time to do a gui using python @Jens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subprocess.call()` waits for the command to finish. Do not use it in  `command` callbacks: it make the GUI unresponsive -- everything is frozen until `call()` returns.

To avoid blocking GUI, you could use `subprocess.Popen()` instead that returns as soon as the child process starts.

If you want to run each command in a new terminal window; see [Execute terminal command from python in new terminal window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308415/execute-terminal-command-from-python-in-new-terminal-window)

Comment: Thanks you I used the subprocess.Popen and it worked