# Python cmd shell send/receive

Tags: python

I want to write a script that opens the cmd shell (windows) issues a command then retrieves the output and sends another command.  So far I'm able to send a command and retrieve the output but the session closes and I don't want that.  I want to keep sending commands to the same cmd window (session).

```
from subprocess import check_output
command = 'dir C:'
out_put = check_output(command, shell=True).decode()
print(out_put)
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19308462/4909087

Comment: I think you need to understand how shells work in general a bit better to be able to clarify what it is that you are really trying to do.