# Execute python file in a new terminal?

Tags: python, subprocess

well, i'm trying to execute a python file in a new terminal.
I've tried several thing, no result.
I read this [Execute terminal command from python in new terminal window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308415/execute-terminal-command-from-python-in-new-terminal-window)
So i tried

```
subprocess.call(['gnome-terminal', '-x', 'python /root/Desktop/Script/website/bb.py'])
```

it opens me a new terminal but it says me "no such file or directory". i've tried differents paths without results.

What i'm doing wrong ?

Thanks
i

Comment: Show the output of `ls -l /root/Desktop/Script/website`

Comment: Also, show us the output of `which python` and see what happens when you replace 'python' (3rd element of argument of `call`) with that result, being full path to python interpreter.

Comment: Hi, here the result of ls

Comment: -rw-rw-r-- 1 root root    95 Mar 24 21:02 bb.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  1121 Mar 24 21:03 main.py

Comment: and which python is /usr/bin/python. I've tried subprocess.call(['gnome-terminal', '-x', '/usr/bin/python /root/Desktop/Script/website/bb.py']) without result

Answer (score 1):

it seems the warning because unproper path writing as you expected therefore you have to take care if these notes

- path separator differs on operation system. *Windows* uses backslash `\`, Linux&Mac use slash `/`
- in windows Desktop folder lies on `C:\\Users\[username]\Desktop`, on linux `/home/[username]/Desktop`
- you can use os.path package to handle paths `os.path.join`

**Tip**
drag the script file into your terminal to get the absolute path located on your file system

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm on linux. So i use backslash

Comment: `/` is actually forward slash

Comment: I made a mistake, i'm using slash not backslash