# How to Open Cmd With Python Then open a file in the new Cmd - Windows

Tags: python, cmd

Basically what I'm looking to do is to have python code that I can run from cmd that opens a new cmd window then types commands into it. I have been able to open and run commands but the commands always run in the first cmd window. I think I might need to switch the cursor or something like that, but I don't know how. 
Here is my current code. 
    import subprocess

subprocess.call('start', shell=True)

import time
time.sleep(5)

cmd=['', ''] ### In the second '' you can type in cmd.
for each in cmd:

```
process=subprocess.Popen(each,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)

output=process.communicate()[0]

print(output.decode('utf-8'))
```

- Thanks

EDIT :

NVM Its in the similar one

Comment: What code are you using to run commands in the first cmd window?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute terminal command from python in new terminal window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308415/execute-terminal-command-from-python-in-new-terminal-window)

Comment: Here is the Code:

Comment: import subprocess

cmd=[' ', ' '] ### In the second ' ' you can type in cmd.
for each in cmd:

 process=subprocess.Popen(each,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)

 output=process.communicate()[0]

 print(output.decode('utf-8'))

Comment: Please update your original question instead of writing code in comments. It is very hard to read them there.