# How can I make a Python program open a terminal window

Tags: python, terminal, window

I'm creating a Python program. I came across a situation I would need to open a terminal window, does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: are you not already running python from a terminal?

Comment: Look at module `subprocess`.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308415/execute-terminal-command-from-python-in-new-terminal-window

Comment: it's cause i want my executable file to open a terminal window