# How do I project Python terminal to another window?

Tags: python, terminal, window, hud

So, basically I need to make a code that ask the user some questions and they must answer, but the person who requested the project asked for a better looking HUD for asking the questions and getting the answers. Is it possible to do it in a separate window? I was thinking I could somehow use pygame for this purpose but dont even know where to begin with it

I tried lots of tutorials from the internet but the best I got was to use the same terminal in another window, but still "raw". I was expecting to get a orange'ish screen with green letters asking for user inputs and then showing the results, and, if possible, for the final text to be copyable using the mouse arrow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute terminal command from python in new terminal window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308415/execute-terminal-command-from-python-in-new-terminal-window)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need a GUI library.

## Tkinter

> The tkinter package ("Tk interface") is the standard Python interface to the Tcl/Tk GUI toolkit. Both Tk and tkinter are available on most Unix platforms, including macOS, as well as on Windows systems.

[tkinter - Docs Python](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/tkinter.html) is a built-in library so it comes pre-installed with the Python installation, making it easy to get started without having to install any additional packages.

## pyimgui

> Python bindings for the amazing dear imgui C++ library - a Bloat-free Immediate Mode Graphical User Interface.

[pyimgui](https://pyimgui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is based on dear imgui, a popular C++ library for creating GUI applications, which provides a fast and efficient way to create GUI interfaces.

## Kivy

> Kivy is an open source software library for the rapid development of applications equipped with novel user interfaces, such as multi-touch apps.

[Kivy](https://kivy.org/) is more focused on app development and support web-inspired ways of designing the UI.