# How do you run multiple files in multiple terminal windows using python

Tags: python, subprocess

```
from subprocess import call
call(["python3", "/home/johngr/psdirc/TestBot1.py"]) and call(["python3", "/home/johngr/psdirc/TestBot2.py"]) and call(["python3", "/home/johngr/psdirc/TestBot3.py"])
```

The call is working but it only runs the first file. I want them all to run in their own terminal windows.

Comment: This question is unclear. Do you want to run them serially? At a time? What do you mean "in a own cmd"?

Comment: "in multiple cmds" -- `cmd.exe` is a shell; it has nothing to do with terminal windows. This question would be clearer if you said "in multiple windows", though you'd need to also specify your operating system, since any kind of dealing with windows is OS-specific.

Comment: I need them to run in multiple windows.

Comment: @handsomebob10, any reason why you are changing your code? This most recent change invalidates one of the answers.

Comment: gunr2171 I tried CivFan's suggestion it gave same results as Padraic Cunningham's answer I just removed the ands.

Comment: @handsomebob10, don't change the code in your question, the only thing you needed to do was add that you want each script run in it's own terminal window, that is the most important part of the question.

Comment: Padraic Cunningham oh ok sorry for that.

Comment: @handsomebob10, have you run the code I added?

Comment: I ran it and got: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled.py", line 26, in <module>
    call(['gnome-terminal', '-e', "python3 /home/johngr/psdirc/TestBot1.py"])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: what terminal do you have installed?

Comment: @handsomebob10, well, that means you don't have `gnome-terminal` installed. Depending on your operating system, this may or may not be expected. Have you actually told anyone what OS you're running? (I **did** say, an hour or so ago, that "you'd need to also specify your operating system").

Comment: Oh I have LXTerminal my operative system is ubuntu. Sorry for not specifying.

Comment: related: [Execute terminal command from python in new terminal window?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19308415/4279)

Comment: [keep multiple cmd windows open from batch](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12144179/4279)

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `and` just run one after the other:

```
call(["python3", "/home/johngr/psdirc/TestBot1.py"])
call(["python3", "/home/johngr/psdirc/TestBot2.py"])
call(["python3", "/home/johngr/psdirc/TestBot3.py"])
```

If you don't want them to wait for the process to finish before starting the next use Popen:

```
 Popen(["python3", "/home/johngr/psdirc/TestBot1.py"])
 Popen(["python3", "/home/johngr/psdirc/TestBot2.py"])
 Popen(["python3", "/home/johngr/psdirc/TestBot3.py"])
```

`call` will *Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return the returncode attribute.* where `Popen` won't wait.

If you want to be sure each process exits with a non-zero exit status use [check_call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) which will raise a CalledProcessError for any non-zero exit status.

To open a terminal for each you can use `gnome-terminal` with `-e`     *Execute the argument to this option inside the terminal*:

```
call(['gnome-terminal', '-e', "python3 /home/johngr/psdirc/TestBot1.py"])
call(['gnome-terminal', '-e', "python3 /home/johngr/psdirc/TestBot2.py"])
call(['gnome-terminal', '-e', "python3 /home/johngr/psdirc/TestBot3.py"])
```

If you want to open tabs you can use `--tab -e`:

```
cmd =['gnome-terminal', '--tab', '-e', 'python3 /home/johngr/psdirc/TestBot1.py',
      '--tab', '-e','python3 /home/johngr/psdirc/TestBot2.py','--tab', '-e', 
      'python 3 /home/johngr/psdirc/TestBot3.py']
call(cmd)
```

You don't seem to have gnome-terminal so just replace it with `lxterminal`:

```
call(['lxterminal', '-e', 'python3 /home/johngr/psdirc/TestBot1.py'])
```

Not sure if  `--tab` option is supported or not, I don't see any reference to it in the documentation.

Comment: I removed the and and made them one after other but it's still opening 1 window.

Comment: What are you running?

Comment: Are you saying you want to open a shell for each process?

Comment: Yes cause they require a shell for each file.

Comment: A shell for each, or a terminal window for each? They're not the same thing.

Comment: I need a terminal window for each I believe.

Comment: @handsomebob. What os?

Answer (score 1):

### Answer to updated question

Use `subprocess.Popen`:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

bot1 = Popen(["lxterminal", "-e", "python3", "-i", "/home/johngr/psdirc/TestBot1.py"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
bot2 = Popen(["lxterminal", "-e", "python3", "-i", "/home/johngr/psdirc/TestBot2.py"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
bot3 = Popen(["lxterminal", "-e", "python3", "-i", "/home/johngr/psdirc/TestBot3.py"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
```

This will put each into its own window. The `-i` option for `python3` is to make the window interactive after the `TestBot3.py` script finishes. It doesn't hurt to have, even if you don't expect it to be interactive, so you can debug in case something does go wrong.

I did a test, and the new windows persist after exiting this script.

### Answer to original question

I don't recommend this for production code, but:

```
not call(["python3", "/home/johngr/psdirc/TestBot1.py"]) \
    and not call(["python3", "/home/johngr/psdirc/TestBot2.py"]) \
    and not call(["python3", "/home/johngr/psdirc/TestBot3.py"])
```

Python treats the bash "Good" return code of 0 as False, and the `and` operator is lazy.

This of course presumes you expect each call to succeed, otherwise you will still not call all three. So you're much better off calling each on a separate line. Wrap it in a function if you want to clean up the code.

Comment: Oh nvm I got it working :D it's LXTerminal in lower case xD. lxterminal. Thank you for your help. The result is: call(["lxterminal", "-e", "python3", "/home/johngr/psdirc/TestBot2.py"])
call(["lxterminal", "-e", "python3", "/home/johngr/psdirc/TestBot3.py"])