# Python/Bash disappearing terminal when accessing relative directory

Tags: python, bash, permissions

So, I have a python script as follows:

```
#! /bin/bash
import os

def addword(run):
    os.system("gnome-terminal --working-directory=../dictionary -e 'python3 addto.py'")
```

The spawned terminal disappears immediately when I run `addword(0)` which should, to my knowledge, run addword as if it were a program. Is there a simple way to fix this? There is a 'dictionary' directory a directory higher than where this is being executed.

*I'm on Ubuntu 15.04*

Comment: Why are you opening in the pwd?

Comment: Looking back on it, I honestly have no idea. The pwd has since been removed.

Comment: I would use subprocess, do you just want to run a python script? Do you really need to open a terminal?

Comment: Yes, I do need to open a terminal given the context of the program. The post has been edited according to a more current situation. I'm not sure I understand how subprocess works, I'll go have a quick look.

Comment: what does `addto.py` do?

Comment: It allows me to add words to a complete English dictionary. This is spawned as a child of a larger program so that it can run independently of the mother program.

Comment: You can still run the program without opening a terminal

Comment: Anyway is this closer to what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30266166/how-do-you-run-multiple-files-in-multiple-terminal-windows-using-python/30266259#30266259?

Comment: The mother program constantly has a terminal open for running commands on it using a `while` loop. I need access to both this terminal input() and the `addto.py` simultaneously.

Comment: No worries, on another note `#!/usr/bin/env python` would probably be more apt at the top of you script.