# Use several Terminal Window in python

Tags: windows, visual-studio, python-2.7

Is there any way to use more than one terminal window in Python in Visual Studio 2013 in Windows?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30266166/how-do-you-run-multiple-files-in-multiple-terminal-windows-using-python

Comment: I have only one .py file..I want to add more terminal window to my program