# Open Python Functions in Multi terminal

Tags: python

I would like to know how can I open two python functions on the same script and display them in different terminals

```
def fn1():
    print ("1 function")

def fn2():
    print("2 function")
```

**I know with subprocess one can open two scripts in different terminal eg:**

```
subprocess.call (['lxterminal', '-e',"python3", "/home/pi/m/code/sensor1.py"])

subprocess.call (['lxterminal', '-e',"python3", "/home/pi/m/code/sensor2.py"])
```

HOW CAN I DO THE ABOVE WITH FUNCTION IN THE SAME SCRIP.

Thank YOU :)

Comment: This was already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30266166/how-do-you-run-multiple-files-in-multiple-terminal-windows-using-python

call(["lxterminal", "-e", "python3", "/path/to/file.py"])

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you run multiple files in multiple terminal windows using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30266166/how-do-you-run-multiple-files-in-multiple-terminal-windows-using-python)